# Virtualenvwrapper WORK_ON

Tags: python, virtualenvwrapper

In virtualenvwrapper, is it possible to have my app files in a different folder than the file created each time you mkvirtualenv ?

```
#virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME="$HOME/.virtualenv"
export PROJECT_HOME="$HOME/Dev/"
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

I have the code above in my .bachrc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `MKPROJECT` will seperate the the files, so the files that created each time you make a project will be in `.virtualen` and the dev files that you will be working on will be in your '`PROJECT_HOME'`